# Is there an issue with MyOpenID?

Tags: support, openid, myopenid

It might be too localized a question, but I'm having issues all of a sudden logging in via [MyOpenID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID#OpenID_Providers). I can log in to my account directly at the site (`myopenid.com`), but I get a "No OpenID endpoint found" error when I try to log in from, say, `superuser.com`.

Strangely, though, sites I was already logged into are fine (like Meta Stack Overflow and Stack Overflow).

Is this just my problem or are others seeing it too?

Comment: Yes, they're having issues.  I see an error if I go to myopenid.com and try to sign in there - completely independent of SE.

Comment: related: [unable to log in using myOpenID.com](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131965/unable-to-log-in-using-myopenid-com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the problem has passed.  Thanks!