# unable to log in using myOpenID.com

Tags: support, login, myopenid

I have started a new job, and from the new work computer, I am unable to login to stackoverflow.com using myOpenID. I get the message:

`Unable to log in with your OpenID provider: No OpenID endpoint found.`

From the question [I Can't Log In With My OpenID — Troubleshooting Tips](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1774/i-cant-log-in-with-my-openid-troubleshooting-tips), I wonder if it is issue #7. When I try to access any page at [myOpenID](http://myopenid.com), it takes a very long time (often several minutes!) before the page appears. So I have created this temporary account (using a google address), in order to ask this question.

Is there any way around this? Can I change my old account to not use openID any more, but connect to it using a different login method?

Comment: You can use the email address you used for this temporary account to log onto your ordinary SO account now - I've merged the two.

Comment: Ah! Thank you! Should I go ahead and delete this "temporary" account?

Comment: You don't have to - like I said, I merged them, so it's now just "your MSO account".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Due to the many issues we have seen with myopenid.com we no longer can recommend them as your primary login provider.  If you currently have a myOpenId account we would highly recommend adding another login method using StackExchange, Google, or Facebook.  There are some helpful instructions on our blog on how to do this here:  https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/we-now-support-multiple-openids/

We will not disable MyOpenId but we will soon be demoting them from the list of large top level login methods available on the login page.

Here's how it will look - you may have to first click "**Show more login options …**" on the login page.

[image: myOpenId moved]

Comment: This is quite disappointing.  I hate the fact that I have to set up an account with a third party--and deal with their terms and privacy nonsense--just to use StackOverflow.  I guess I'll have to check out StackExchange's own OpenID option.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy the StackExchange login option is a excellent choice - you should find it to be a lot faster and more reliable than MyOpenID

Comment: What about delegation through my open id?  Will you be supporting that?

Comment: We support any OpenId provider that supports the spec, however we don't recommend using a login provider that is unreliable - that includes delegated provider logins.

Comment: @GeoffDalgas I think what I meant was, can I delegate my open id url through a Stack Exchange login/open id?

Comment: Yes you can - @balpha currently has this configured for his login and it works fine.

Comment: What are the recommended OpenId providers?