# Logon id not found

Tags: support, stack-overflow, openid

I have a user on stackover (theblitz).

I want to use the same user on a different computer but I can't figure out my login.
I thought I used an openid (myopenid.com).
When I click on "My Logins" I see that that login is there (it is the only one there).

However, when I enter the user on the login page (myopenid.com/theblitz) I get the error "No endpoint found."

This user is one I set up accidently a long time ago.

So, how do I get my correct user on my other computer

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're having [the same problem as this user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131965/unable-to-log-in-using-myopenid-com), which has unfortunately been diagnosed as one related to the MyOpenId provider, not something that Stack Exchange can fix.

The best thing to do would be to [add another OpenID identity to your account](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/we-now-support-multiple-openids/), using another OpenID service like Google, Facebook, or even the Stack Exchange OpenID provider. You can have as many OpenIDs associated with your account as you want, and they'll all log you in as the same user—very handy for fallbacks.

Comment: This (temporary) user is connected through my FB id. It there any way to merge them?

Comment: @JonathanBlitz email `team@stackoverflow.com` and they can manually merge your two accounts together.

Comment: @Jonathan The comprehensive FAQ on merging accounts is [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist). Basically, you can try flagging one of your posts for moderator attention and asking for a merge. This is a good option if it's *very clear* that they represent the same person. Otherwise, you'll need to email the team like nhinkle suggested.