# What happened to MyOpenID?

Tags: support, openid, myopenid

Apologies if this has been covered.  A search didn't find the answer I seek.

While trying to log in to a beta site (Writers.SE, if it matters) for the first time today, I found that the MyOpenID icon is not to be found:

[image]

I confirmed the behavior on another site I've never used, RPG.SE.

Yet I remain logged in on the various other sites using the only account I've ever used, which is a MyOpenID account.

Is MyOpenID support gone? If so, please point me to the relevant announcement and/or documentation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [unable to log in using myOpenID.com](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131965/unable-to-log-in-using-myopenid-com)

Comment: @The Establishment: I don't think so...

Comment: @Bolt The answer is precisely the same. Anyway, it was more of a hint to [do this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132384/what-happened-to-myopenid#comment366154_132385).

Comment: Duplicate answers don't imply duplicate questions. Besides, should this be closed, we wouldn't be able to do that anymore.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We now de-emphasize MyOpenID as a login option due to the large number of problems they've been having lately.

You can still sign in with it (provided their end of the bargain works) by typing the URL manually or clicking "Show more login options..." and using the MyOpenID button there as before.

Related: [unable to log in using myOpenID.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131965/unable-to-log-in-using-myopenid-com/)

Comment: +1 I've been getting certificate warnings when I visit the site directly on Dolphin, and use my Google login instead here.

Comment: I think you should move Geoff's answer to that into this question and get rid of the other question. The answer is much more relevant to this specific question, and this question keeps reappearing.