# How to recover my old questions attached to MyOpenID?

Tags: support, myopenid, account-recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happened to MyOpenID?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132384/what-happened-to-myopenid)

It seems that MyOpenID is not longer active to access stackoverflow. I created a new account with stackexchange but how can I link my older MyOpenID account to see my old questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MyOpenID is still active.

You just need to click the "more login options..." link and it's the first one of the second rank.

You should have logged in with that and then added a new OpenID to your existing account - via the "my logins" link on your profile.

However, having created a second account, simply flag one of the original accounts posts and indicate that you'd like the accounts merged.