# What to do about MyOpenID?

Tags: feature-request, myopenid

I have an account where I log into MyOpenID every day while I am work and sit on StackOverflow. Again today for the hundredth time, MyOpenID is down. I would like to make the suggestion that MyOpenID be removed from the available login providers and only be maintained for those who already use it. Additionally, there should be some way to migrate away from MyOpenID (if there is not already).

edit: I've been informed that adding additional accounts can be done to mitigate the effect of a login provider going down, see the comments of this post.

Comment: You can add any number of other accounts to authenticate with. From your profile page, click `My Logins` and add someone who isn't down all the time and that you trust.

Comment: @MartijnPieters well there was one good reason to; SE recently demphasized MyOpenID because of uptime issues I think

Comment: [A while ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132384/what-happened-to-myopenid) MyOpenId was already pushed back in the list of login methods for probably that reasons

Comment: @BenBrocka: Ah, interesting. Still, requiring that it be removed? I'd do that only if the site died completely..

Comment: @MartijnPieters yeah, I think removing it from the immediately obvious/implicitly recommended list is good enough

Comment: @Oded Thanks for this information. I still think my point to deemphasize MyOpenID permanently makes sense though.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I was saying that it should be removed for new StackExchange signups/users, not for existing MyOpenID users. I don't see why my question gets downvotes just because people have a different opinion.

Comment: @BenBrocka I agree with you, removing it from the recommendations list would be good enough to me. When I signed up it was on that list and I chose it for ease of signup and because it didn't require access to external accounts like my google account.

Comment: @Martijn, it seems to be left dying; see chb's answer.

Answer (score 8):

The myopenid service is no [longer supported by Janrain](https://twitter.com/Janrain/status/349576783563202561).

You're not alone in having missed the memo. There are quite a few people who are wondering what happened to the service, myself included.

Comment: It looks like myOpenID is down for the count.  They've be down for well over 48 hours now.  From their downtime history, they've been very poor at maintaining service.  Looks like they're just gonna let it die.

Comment: I just noticed this too!

Comment: Looks like it's time to remove myOpenID entirely from the list of login providers.

Comment: And notify users, who use it as the only login provider.

Comment: @Calmarius, give [Publicise loss of myOpenID](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189701/publicise-loss-of-myopenid) a vote, if you didn't already.