# Stackexchange.com still shows MyOpenID login as recommended

Tags: bug, status-completed, openid, stackexchange.com, myopenid

From the question [unable to log in using myOpenID.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131965/unable-to-log-in-using-myopenid-com) it seems MyOpenID is no longer recommended, bringing down the list of OpenIDs you see at login to four. Since this simplifies the interface and we've apparently had issues with MyOpenID it seems like a good idea to remove MyOpenID's icon.

But www.stackexchange.com still shows it for an option:

[image]

Turns out this shows up on Careers too:

[image]

Shouldn't it be removed just like it is on all the other sites?

Comment: It also shows up on Data Explorer, but that even displays AOL as a primary provider, so... :P

Comment: @TimStone oh wow, and no Facebook openID there either...

Comment: Nope. I'll make a note...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MyOpenID has been relegated on the [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/users/login), [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/login), and [Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/users/login) login pages.

Comment: I assume data.SE is a special case because it's log in is...weird?

Comment: @BenBrocka I think it's more that it's just so far removed from any of those code bases. You're free to [poke at it yourself](http://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/source/browse/) of course, but otherwise I'll be sure to do something with it once I finish working on some higher priority updates.