# How do I access my previous StackExchange myOpenId account?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, login, user-accounts, openid

I've an existing StackExchange account with the following myOpenId:
sidharth-panwar.myopenid.com

But I'm not able to log in with this account. Whenever I try to log in it gives me the following error message:

> No OpenID endpoint found.

I've logged in with a temporary account (using my GMail account). Is it possible to link my GMail account with my myOpenId account so that my profile remains intact?

I've gone through the following threads already before posting:

- [unable to log in using myOpenID.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131965/unable-to-log-in-using-myopenid-com)
- [Can't log in with my OpenID - Troubleshooting Tips](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1774/cant-log-in-with-my-openid-troubleshooting-tips)

Comment: myOpenId.com has shut down altogether now, the OpenID endpoint is *no more*.

Comment: *After February 1, you will no longer be able to use myOpenID to log in to Stack Exchange. Stack Exchange will not be able to answer any questions about why myOpenID is down or when it will be working again. If you do not have any other login credentials on your account by February 1, you will be locked out, and Stack Exchange will be unlikely to help you recover your account.*

Comment: If you still know the email address, try out the procedure as lined out in [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197819/140890).

Comment: I saw that shog9 was able to help one of the users by mapping his account with the temporary email account and hoped that something could be done for my case... Let me try your suggestion Martijn... Thanks

Comment: I don't see any recover option on login page for myopenid...

Comment: I *think* that post refers to: https://stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery

Comment: Ok. Am trying with this one... let's see if this one works...